# ActiveMerchant gem not allowing MasterCard 2-BIN ranges

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemerchant

I am using `activemerchant` gem with my application for payment processing through credit card.But it is not allowing latest MasterCard 2-BIN ranges from 222100 to 272099.

When I am validating card with this number(`2221000000000009`) getting below error:

```
 Brand does not match the card number.
```

Is there any update on this gem for allowing latest series numbers?

Comment: Did you define ELECTRON_RANGES ?

Comment: How can I add this? Do I need to modify plugin?